# Read variable from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

Im having trouble with a contact form and reading a variable from a drop down.

The code I have is this for the drop down:

```
<label for="Cttl">Title :</label>
<select name="Cttl" onchange='CheckCttl(this.value);'> 
<option>Choose your title</option>  
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="other">other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="Cttl" id="Cttl" placeholder="Please specifiy" style='display:none;'/>
```

When the other option is selected and the user enters something in the input box , the email sent from the form contains what they have typed, eg:

Title : What I typed

If they choose another option such as Mr or Mrs , the email comes back blank like this :

Title :

Is there any what to solve this?

Other code used in contact form:

the php for actually sending the email (works for inputs):

```
$title= $_POST["Cttl"] ;
```

The js used to save the user inputs for a summary:

```
Ctitle = _("Cttl").value;
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you showed us your JS validation script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the fact that both the select field and input field have the same name. You could always check the form in PHP with something like this to make sure the title has been filled in properly or one was chosen from your dropdown.

```
<?php

    // Check if they selected other for the title
    if($_POST['select-title'] == 'other') {

        if(!empty($_POST['input-title'])) {

            $title = $_POST['input-title'];

        } else {

            echo 'Your title is empty!'; // The input was empty

        }

    } else {

        $title = $_POST['select-title']

    }
```

Comment: Iv just had a look at the code , I didnt put an id for the drop down box . This has solved half the problem because the summary page now shows what they have selected (Mr , Mrs or what they have typed). The email still shows the field blank.

Comment: Which is why it'd be best to make sure both your select and input fields have different names otherwise you'll only receiving data from your input field.